# Multi project routing does not work on playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, multi-project

Hi I'm trying to set up a multiproject scala playframework project, and I seem to have issues figuring what the issue is with my routing. SBT keeps on giving me cryptic errors. Has anyone else run into this error. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

build.sbt:

```
name := """server"""

libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    guice,
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
  )
}

lazy val static = (project in file("modules/static")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val main = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(static).aggregate(static)
```

conf/routes:

```
-> /static static.Routes
```

modules/static/conf/static.routes

```
GET     /static/index                           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
GET     /static/assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

The error it gives me:

```
\server\modules\static\conf\static.routes: identifier expected but `.' found.
```

And another error that is given if its been compiled and then modified to the routes above:

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[identifier expected but `.' found.]
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1(PlayReload.scala:33)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:28)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:24)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$compile$3(PlayReload.scala:51)
        at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:51)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with my project (Play 2.6):

conf/routes:

`->   /     static.Routes` // at the end of the routing script

modules/static/conf/static.routes:

`GET  /static/index    controllers.Default.redirect(to = "/static/index/")
GET  /static/index/   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")`

If I remember correctly - the missing slash was the problem.

Comment: Yea I changed my route to:
GET     /static/index/                           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")

Still get the same error. Do you have your project on a public repo that I can take a look at?

Comment: Okay so I had a hunch and changed the subproject name to web from static and that worked. I'm guessing maybe its some sort of collision as static can be a reserved word in scala.